# Table cells increases width despite box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to add padding to the cells of my table when I click button `View`, but this increases width of the cell. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280521/table-cells-overflow-despite-box-sizing-border-box) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779434/how-do-i-prevent-the-padding-property-from-changing-width-or-height-in-css) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892733/box-sizing-border-box-not-working), however it still increases the size of the cell.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.move-right div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th>Bar</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
          <tr [ngClass]="{'move-right': item?.show == 1}">
              <td>
                {{ item.foo }}
              </td>
              <td>{{ item.bar }}</td>
              <td>
                <ul  *ngIf="item.items && item.items.length > 0"
                  (click)="(item.show ? (item.show = 0) : (item.show = 1))"> 
                  {{ item.show ? 'Hide' : 'View' }} 
                </ul>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <ng-container *ngIf="item.show==1">
              <tr *ngFor="let num of item.items" class="move-right">                  
                  <td> <div>{{num}} </div> </td>
                  <td> <div>{{ num }}</div> </td>
                  <td> <div>{{ num }}</div> </td>
              </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[This is a reproduced behavior at the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwzy5c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).  Please click `View` in the table to reproduce such behavior.

What I have now:

[image]

After `View` button is clicked, then the width of columns became wider:

[image]

How to avoid of increasing cell width? I just would like to move text slightly to the right side of **only `td` which contains data 'a', 'b', 'c' and '1' and '2'.**, not in all cells.

It is not desirable to change the columns width on click along with that and I would like those 3 columns to move to the right on 80px?

Comment: What do you really want to do? You are using item?.show and there is no show property in your  dataset. you need to apply css  on td to make it work.

Comment: @Prince I am sorry, I forgot to write that it is necessary to click `View` in the table to reproduce such behavior

Comment: The default cell width is 50px and you add a padding of 100px when clicking on `View`. The cell width will increase to accomodate it. Try adding a padding of 20px instead; the cell width will not change.

Comment: @ConnorsFan could you show in code, please, what you mean?

Comment: See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubazha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code, I was able to validate with you angular code:

```
*{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid red;
color:red;

}

table tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

ul{
padding:0;
}  

 .move-right td{     
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding-left:80px;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! Thank you, master! Have a nice day! Could you add a little bit explanation of reason of increasing width? :)

Comment: Usually Table, and td will shrink and expand based on the contents unless you specify how much width you size for the column for Ex. if you have 4 columns with 100% width then it is good to fix the width of 25% each for the columns so that the td won't change w.r.t data, so in your case that is what happened, when the padding executes it changes it's width based on the movement, so either you can fix the table layout or fix the td width. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
table tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.move-right div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 5px;   /* change this from 100 to 5px */
  font-weight: bold;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Hope this will help.